# How to stop a R function if it runs for more than 30 Minutes?

Tags: r, function, time-limiting

I am testing my code using multiple methods.

If a certain method/function, say `glm()` takes more than 30 minutes, I want to kill that function and proceed onto the next one, without terminating my R session.

In other words, is there a way to set a time limit on an R function and move on to the next step?